# Proof that $a + b \sqrt D$ has unique representation

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Dummit and Foote, 3rd Edition, p.227, example 5.

> Let $D$ be a rational number that is not a perfect square in
>   $\mathbb{Q}$ and define
>
> \begin{equation} \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D) = \{a + b \sqrt D|a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\} \end{equation}
>
> as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$

Then it says:

> It is easy to show that the assumption that $D$ is not a square implies that every element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt D)$ may be written uniquely in the form $a + b \sqrt D$.

I tried to prove it by writing that $d = \sqrt{D}$ is not in $\mathbb{N}$, supposing that $a + b d = a' + b' d$, and trying to deduce $a = a'$ and $b = b'$. Can somehow help me ?

Comment: You need to assume $d\notin\mathbb Q,$ not $d\notin\mathbb N.$

Comment: Use the fact that this would imply $(a-a^{\prime}) = (b^{\prime}-b)d $ (or, $(a-a^{\prime}) + (b-b^{\prime})d = 0$).

Comment: The question says “a perfect square in $\mathbb Q,$” which includes $9/4.$ $D=9/4$ is a perfect square in  the rationals.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you ! I just got that thank to you previous comment. The definitions I found online where given for integers, hence my confusion !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$ is the smallest subfield of $\Bbb C$ containing both $\Bbb Q$ and $\sqrt D$; it is easy to see that in fact

$\Bbb Q(\sqrt D) = \{ a + b \sqrt D, \; a, b \in \Bbb Q \}, \tag 1$

the set on the right is obviously closed under addition, and as for multiplication we have

$(a + b\sqrt D)(c + e\sqrt D)$
$= (ac + beD) + (bc + ae)\sqrt D \tag 2$

with

$ac + beD, bc + ae \in \Bbb Q; \tag 3$

also, every $a + b\sqrt D$ is possessed of a multiplicative inverse of the same form, for

$a^2 - b^2D \ne 0 \tag 4$

lest

$D = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2} = \left (\dfrac{a}{b} \right)^2,  \tag 5$

and $D$ is a perfect square in $\Bbb Q$; in light of (4) we may write

$(a + b\sqrt D)\dfrac{a - b\sqrt D}{a^2 - b^2D} = \dfrac{ (a + b\sqrt D)( a - b\sqrt D)}{a^2 - b^2D} = \dfrac{a^2 - b^2D}{a^2 - b^2D} = 1, \tag 6$

whence

$(a + b\sqrt D)^{-1} = \dfrac{a - b\sqrt D}{a^2 - b^2D}, \tag 7$

explicitly presenting the inverse of $a + b\sqrt D$;  thus

$\{ a + b \sqrt D, \; a, b ,\in \Bbb Q \} \tag 8$

is in fact the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$.

The above remarks may stray a little far a-*field* from the central point of the question itself, but I think they may provide some extended context  into which this question fits.  As for the mainline inquiry, an answer is tacitly suggested in the observation (4)-(5) that there is no pair $a, b \in \Bbb Q$ for which

$a^2 - b^2D = 0, \tag 9$

for if an element of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)$ were *not* uniquely so represented, we would have

$a, b, c, e \in \Bbb Q \tag{10}$

with

$a + b\sqrt D = c + e\sqrt D; \tag{11}$

then

$(a - c) + (b - d)\sqrt D = 0, \tag{12}$

and in a manner similar to Thomas Shelby in his answer we argue that in the case

$b - d = 0 \tag{13}$

we have

$a = c, \tag{13}$

and uniqueness follows; on the other hand,

$b - d \ne 0 \tag{14}$

allows us to write

$\sqrt D = -\dfrac{a - c}{b - d} \in \Bbb Q, \tag{15}$

$D = \left (\dfrac{a - c}{b - d}\right )^2 \in \Bbb Q, \tag{16}$

contrary to the hypothesis that $D$ is not a perfect square in $\Bbb Q$; thus (14) is ruled out and the uniqueness of $a + b\sqrt D$ binds.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $a+b\sqrt D=0$. I claim that $a=b=0$. Note that if $b=0$, then $a=0$. If $b\neq 0$, we have  $$D=\frac{a^2}{b^2}, $$ a contradiction.